# Rotate textfile upside down with batch

Tags: batch-file

I got a textfile like this

```
11111
2222
3333
44
```

and i want to turn it upside down with a batch file

```
44
3333
2222
11111
```

any hint highly appreciated....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for a reasonable number of lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=2000000000
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filein.txt) do (
set /a c=c-1
set "line[!c!]=%%a"
)
(for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (' set line[ ') do echo %%b)>output.txt
endlocal
```

Comment: youre the batch expert here ^^

Comment: there is no %%b defined ?

Comment: What is your question?  Does it fail with your text?

Answer (score 1):

try it with the Unix tool [tac](/questions/tagged/tac) ([CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)):

```
tac filein.txt > fileout.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your text doesn't contain `"`. Then:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
COPY NUL reversed_text_file.txt
FOR /F "DELIMS=*" %%l IN (your_text_file.txt) DO (
    SET "line=%%l"
    ECHO.!line!>temp_line.txt
    COPY temp_line.txt+reversed_text_file.txt
    MOVE /Y temp_line.txt reversed_text_file.txt
)
```

If you can't guarantee there's non quote characters you should try another solution other then batch.

EDIT: Improvement!